# Is there a way of clustering Latitude and longitude to the nearest town in power BI without being given the town names?

Tags: powerbi, maps, gis

I have a list of 12000 User Ids and their Lat and Long.

I need to make a map visualization in power Bi showing towns and their densities in terms of no of users. When I visualize it as it is, I get the single points scattered all over the map.

Any help on how to achieve this. currently the data is in excel.

Answer (score 0):

if you familiar with **Python** language, you can use [GeoPy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library To find the address corresponding to a set of coordinates.

- Example:

Input

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
```

Output

```
Flatiron Building, 175, 5th Avenue, Flatiron, New York, NYC, New York, ...
```

and then you can use [Pandas](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjcv6aNxtbxAhWOHewKHfkqCjIQFjAAegQIBhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw3cD5ulu4AnZcNusojIyttY) library to read [CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) files and [Excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)